# What is the corresponding of Algorithm in Modelling language?

Tags: algorithm, uml, modeling

When we write code in some programming languages such as Java there is an algorithm which is a set of steps to produce the result
but when we are working with Modelling language such as UML , What will be the corresponding to the Algorithm in UML?

is it a methodology ?

Comment: Do you mean an activity diagram? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409465.aspx

Comment: UML is generally not enough of a language to describe an algorithm. Algorithms are described with pseudo-code.

Comment: No I didn't,@DavidBrabant,
I am asking about if we think of problem in terms of Modelling What can we use instead of Algorithm in programming Language?

Comment: I'm not certain, but you may be looking for the UML concept of a _behavior_. This is an abstraction of the concept of "something happens". For instance, a method may be associated with a behavior, an action may have a behavior, a state machine transition may have a behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms apply to modeling languages such as UML. The sequence diagrams are perfectly capable of depicting algorithms. However when it comes to modeling, most people think program structure (e.g. class diagram) instead of program behavior (e.g. sequence diagram).

If you are trying to find a *structural* equivalent to the *behavioral* algorithm, the closest answer you can get is probably [*design pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

Behavioral algorithms are (usually) reusable sets of steps for solving a behavioral problem. Sorting and searching are the usual examples with several well known algorithms.

In modeling the reusable designs that solve structural problems are called design patterns. The problems these solve may relate to data composition, behavioral structures, etc. The full topic of design patterns is a bit too broad for an answer, so I'll just provide a  [link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).